# how to remove '[' ']' from output in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

How to remove '['']' from the java output. I need to print them without the square brackets as it is my requirement.

Code has been attached below.

```
package Datas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SortingLists {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> animals = new ArrayList<String>();
    animals.add("tiger");
    animals.add("cat");
    animals.add("snake");
    animals.add("dog");
    //Sort by alphabet
    Collections.sort(animals);

    System.out.println(animals);    

    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    nums.add(3);
    nums.add(36);
    nums.add(73);
    nums.add(40);
    nums.add(1);
    //Sort number
    Collections.sort(nums);

    System.out.println(nums);
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to print an ArrayList differently from the default ToString, then just iterate through the Array List and print the elements the way you want to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `String.join` since Java 8:

```
String.join(",", animals);
```

The first argument to `join` is the delimiter. You can change that a different string if desired.

For non-string collections, you may have to convert to string:

```
String.join(",", 
       nums.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: @OleV.V. : One thing I've missed is that the other question is about `android`, don't know if `String.join` is available there, maybe it would be `TextUtils.join` .(Just asked to reopen the current question because of this).

Comment: I’m not an Android programmer myself, but under the impression that `String.join` and other Java 8 stuff is available in the newest Android versions.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll add the answer to that question.